# Font-Face - the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I want to load 6 fonts, so i download the fonts and implement them inside my css file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "TTNorms";
    src: local('TT Norms Pro Regular'), url("../fonts/Copytext/TT\ Norms\ Pro\ Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

After loading the css in set the different fonts to different areas like this

```
<div class="col" style="font-family TTNorms !important"> some text </div>
```

If I open the website local everything works perfectly but if I upload to webspace I get error Messages:

### Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

I dont understand why the fonts arent loading with error 403.. there are license free. Is there something missing?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the font license. It's the permissions of the folder that contains the fonts. First fix the path in your src: line - then check permissions of that folder on your webserver. Ensure it is 755

Comment: Thanks @fraggley now it works, can you explain why I have to set 755 to every FontsFile or why its not automatically 755?

Comment: It will just be the way your web server is configured - and how you have uploaded the fonts. I'll submit an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving a 403 error because your server is saying you don't have permission to access those fonts. To access them:

1. Clean up the path to your font files in the src: line of your CSS
2. On your server, update the permissions of your font folder (and fonts) to 755

Answer (score -2):

Figure it out, if you have problems loading fonts, material design icons and appear message of 403 forbidden. You need to go AWS S3 click in your bucket go to Permissions> Block Public Access Settings  and turn them OFF.

Then go to the files that you have problems with in the bucket and in action make them public. That will solve the problem loading fonts, material design icons, etc.